# Pirates keep wanting my cargo, but I have nothing

Tags: elite-dangerous

I am new to Elite: Dangerous and pirates keep wanting my cargo. They try to intercept me at each FSD, even when my cargo is empty. I only have a Sidewinder and most of time I have transport missions.

Why are they doing that ? How can I prevent this from happening ? That's really annoying...

Comment: You should state if you play in Open, Solo or Private to help a little with this game.   TBH the NPCs tend to attack in Solo even if you have nothing, so that could very well be the case here.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I play in solo. ("Online singleplayer")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't really prevent them from trying to intercept you randomly, however know that pirates are not dumb and won't usually (always?) shoot you down if you don't have any valuable cargo.

Otherwise, here are some tips to evade encounters:

- Avoid standing in the same place too long. I've found myself getting interdicted a lot less by simply always being on the move, never staying in a system or undocked longer than I have to.
- You can simply avoid FSD interdiction by aligning the escape vector during interdiction. This is the primary mean to avoid being intercepted.
- If you do get intercepted, but don't have any actual cargo and the target is not hostile to you for some reason, you can just stay put and let them scan you. They'll fire off some mean remarks and let you leave.
- Finally, if things come to worse and you know they're going to be hostile, it's a good idea to divert power to engines, use your afterburner to steer away from the enemies, and engage stealth mode. Depending on the kind of reactor you're using, you might have to fly with heatsink launchers for this to be effective.
- As an aditional tip, the jump gravity interference formula depends on *relative* ship mass. This usually means that ships with higher mass will take less time to jump when interdicted by ships with lower mass.

Comment: To avoid the confrontation, you can also submit to the interdiction (that will shorten the FSD cooldown) and then jump into the supercruise again in a few seconds.

Comment: Also, some interdictions are due to security forces doing random patrols, usually around high security systems. Often they'll interdict you right before you arrive at a station, and there's no way to know they're not a pirate unless you submit or fail the interdiction. Very annoying.

Comment: @Dpeif: Err, doesn't the NPC chat you up as they interdict you? They'll say if they're doing a security scan. NPC pirates are pretty honest, so I think you can tell the difference between a security scan and someone wanting what's in your cargo hold.

Comment: @Ellesedil I am pretty sure that when you are interdicted by the security patrol they send you a message, it should be visible in the communication interface(top right corner). Also if you press "select nearest hostile" button while being interdicted (when still in super cruse) you will select the ship that is trying to interdict you, even if they are not hostile. so you can see who is trying to take you out. I usually do this to see if I will be able to take them down or out run them.

Comment: @Pawel: Exactly. And if I recall, NPC pirates will also send you a message about "getting everything you have" or somesuch. If you are successfully interdicted, then they send a second message. That's why I think the comment by Dpeif is incorrect. There *is* a way to know if you're being interdicted by an NPC pirate who wants your stuff, a security NPC who just wants to scan your ship.